# subject: rebuild old c++ dll, Visual Studio? Or what?

Tags: dll, rebuild, visual-studio

Folks:

I need a 8051 processor instruction + internal peripheral simulator to resurrect a very old project. (Long story.)  I found an WinXP-targeted abandonware project that is *almost* perfect for my needs:

```
http://home.arcor.de/jensaltmann/jsim-e.htm
```

It just needs a tiny bit of improvement to support the external memory model I need to use.  (For 8051 fans:  I need external program memory at 0 - 0x7fff to be readable as external data, contiguous with external RAM at 0x8000 - 0xffff.)

The developer/maintainer ran out of time years ago and posted the c++ source code of the front-end GUI and the 8051-specific DLL.

**Notice: Double thanks to the developer for doing the project originally and then posting the source when he could no longer maintain it!**

I've located the code in the DLL source that needs adjustment…  Doesn't look too difficult.

But the developer didn't say anything at all about the development environment.

The DLL source code unzips to a top-level folder named "MSDEV-PRJ" containing about 30 files, of which about 10 are .cpp, probably under 9000 total source lines of what looks like competently written and reasonably documented code. Based on the folder name and the project age I'm guessing this is a MS Visual Studio Project.  I just happen to own a copy of MSVS of about the same vintage, roughly 1995-2000.

My questions:

1. Does finding a folder of this name imply a complete, consistent Visual Studio project is contained within?  That is, does it seem worthwhile to haul out my VS disks, do the install --which I recall can be painful-- and try?
2. What would be the difficulty of using GNU tools, specifically MinGW, which I happen to have already installed,  to do the job?  On a scale of [1] to … [Excruciating] how difficult is this sort of conversion likely to be?
3. Any completely different approaches to this, e.g. another cheap/free dev environment that can import MSVS projects and deal with MS directives? Or maybe someone knows a really good full-featured, low-cost 8051 simulator that I can just buy?

TIA

hen3ry

Answer (score 0):

I found someone with Visual Studio already installed and he was quickly able to verify, "yes" this source is a complete --almost fully consistent-- MSVS project.  It recompiled successfully and seems to function correctly.    With this done, there's no reason to look at other dev environments.

Thanks,

hen3ry